# Uniformly distributed random vector between the $x$ axis and a function of $x$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let the random variable $(X,Y)$ be uniformly distributed in the domain between the $x$ axis and $y=e^{-x^2/2}$.

I have to find whether $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed random varibales, but first I want to know what is the density mass function of $X,Y$.

This confuses me. My best guess is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}$, where $-\infty\leq x\leq\infty$ and $0\leq y \leq e^{-x^2/2}$ since it is uniformly distributed on an area of $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

I have countless doubts with this answer, and a strong feel it is false. So what is the rigth answer? How is it advised to approach this kind of questions?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Of course. This is what I wrote on paper but somehow forgot it here. Thanks.

Comment: Your joint density function is now right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So now, $f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}dy = -\infty+\infty$?..

Comment: For $X$ it is clearest to go after the cdf.  The way your question is currently phrased (joint density) you may not get help, since your joint density is right, and you do not ask about the marginal densities.

Comment: Re your last comment, note that $f_{X,Y}$ is defined on the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$ by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathbf 1_{0<y<e^{-x^2/2}}$$ hence $f_X$ is defined on the whole real line $\mathbb R$ by $$f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb Rf_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int_0^{e^{-x^2/2}}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}.$$ As often, the détour from the joint PDF to the marginal PDF passing by some CDF is quite unneeded and it only complicates things. It is much easier to go straight from PDF to PDF. All that is needed is to remember that *indicator functions are a crucial part of PDFs*.